# Firefox 36 display problems after using Remote Desktop

Tags: firefox, remote-desktop

I accessed my computer via Remote Desktop and when I used it locally again, my Firefox has some issues.

The *Minimize and Maximize and Close buttons* cannot be used, when I click on them, the 'original' Windows theme pops up but none of them works.

[image]

If I grab it with the mouse and unmaximize it, I get this view:

[image]

What's happening with Firefox? How can I avoid this situation? Why can't Firefox handle this situation properly?

Comment: What Remote Desktop software do you use? I know that some change 32-bit color depth to some lower setting. Is the issue related to color depth? Does it occurs when switching? Have you tried to update video card driver?

Comment: I used the built-in Windows 8.1 Remote Desktop with default settings. It occurred when I logged back into my local computer. The VGA driver is the latest, it is an i3-4350 CPU with a CPU-integrated VGA.

Comment: This is probably because compositing is disabled when using RDP (except with RemoteFX). If you think Firefox is misbehaving, do file a bug report.

Comment: I don't think, I know that  FF is misbehaving...it is obviously buggy. I will send them a report.

Answer (score 1):

Some remote desktop applications change Windows theme and color settings for the end user to have better performance. This could have caused the issue. A simple restart would fix everything.

Comment: Okay, I know that a restart would - temporary - solve the issue but why does Firefox behave like this? Why doesn't it correctly handle the color depth change (or whatever is causing this)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but after doing some research, I found that disabling hardware acceleration prevents that from happening.

I hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Super User, thanks for your contribution. Could you please provide steps on how to do that in your answer?

Comment: I intend to use Hardware Acceleration to decrease the load on my CPU. It is a bug in Firefox, so I expect it to be fixed (though as they are 8 years behind Chrome and Internet Explorer with threading, I don't expect too much).

Comment: @Nestor:  Please be sure to let them know how much you paid for their product when you complain.

Comment: @JuliePelletier You mean if it is free, it is allowed to be inferior or useless? I don't think so. As millions of users use their product they should have the decency to provide working solutions. Or don't do it... I know, I can use other browser (which I do except one place). I also think, Chrome should be a working browser, yet they have 3 year old bugs: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=242861